# How to ensure tasks in one celery queue get executed in order

Tags: python, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I am working on set up some celery queues for process some tasks. Each task hashes a value and send this task to a delicate queue based on hashed value. What I want to achieve is, to make sure messages in one celery queue can be executed sequentially.

Task looks like this

```
@app.task(
    acks_late=True,
    autoretry_for=(OperationalError,),
    max_retries=5,
    retry_backoff=True,
    retry_backoff_max=1,
)
def handle_a_task(task):
    # do something
```

Get a dedicated celery queue

```
def get_queue(task_value):
    return md5(task_value)
```

Send task to the queue

```
queue = get_queue()
handle_a_task.apply_async(
    kwargs={
        "task": {"id": 123},
    },
    queue=queue,
)
```

In production, there are multiple celery workers. I've seen these workers would take messages from the same queue and process at the same time. What can I do to make messages in one celery queue get processed in order?

I've tried to do `celery worker --prefetch-multiplier=1`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63933550/serial-processing-of-specific-tasks-using-celery-with-concurrency

Comment: Why do you even need a distributed task queue then? Celery is used to distribute the tasks among workers so that they could be executed in parallel. If all you want is sequential execution, why do you even need multiple workers?